# Calculate minimum number of test cases for statement coverage and condition coverage respectively

Tags: white-box-testing

Could someone draw a flow graph and explain how I get the answer to this question?

Question: Calculate the minimum number of test cases for statement coverage and minimum number of test cases for decision coverage respectively.

READ A
READ B
READ C
IF C>A THEN
IF C>B THEN
PRINT "C MUST BE SMALLER THAN AT LEAST ONE NUMBER"
ELSE
PRINT "PROCEED TO NEXT STAGE"
END IF
ELSE
PRINT "B CAN BE SMALLER THAN C"
END IF

Comment: no.  this isn't a homework site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No need to be rude. I'm new to all this and I couldn't understand how the answer was being reached. I've been drawing out the flow of the code for the ISTQB exams and I just wanted to see the correct way that one would draw it.